# How do I scan every frame from ISampleGrabber using directshow.net

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing, directshow, directshow.net

I have a program which currently displays a preview of a usb webcam and then displays a frame within a picturebox when a button is pressed. This is done by using the directshow DxSnap sample thus using the ISampleGrabberCB interface.

Would it be possible for each frame to be scanned automatically without the use of a button?

I tried to do this with a timer however the result ended with bad image quality from both preview and the captured image.

Would this be achieved by using the IsampleGrabberCB.BufferCB function?

The way I am currently getting frames using is a button consists of:

```
int ISampleGrabberCB.BufferCB(double sampleTime, IntPtr buffer, int bufferLength)
    {
        Debug.Assert(bufferLength == Math.Abs(pitch) * videoHeight, "Wrong Buffer Length");

        if (gotFrame)
        {
            gotFrame = false;
            Debug.Assert(imageBuffer != IntPtr.Zero, "Remove Buffer");

            CopyMemory(imageBuffer, buffer, bufferLength);

            pictureReady.Set();
        }
        return 0;
    }
public void getFrameFromWebcam()
{
   if (iPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
   {
       Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(iPtr);
       iPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
   }

        //Get Image
        iPtr = sampleGrabberCallBack.getFrame();
        Bitmap bitmapOfFrame = new Bitmap(sampleGrabberCallBack.width, sampleGrabberCallBack.height, sampleGrabberCallBack.capturePitch, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, iPtr);
        bitmapOfFrame.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
        pictureBox3.Image = bitmapOfFrame;
        barcodeReader(bitmapOfFrame);
}

public IntPtr getFrame()
    {
        int hr;
        pictureReady.Reset();
        imageBuffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Math.Abs(pitch) * videoHeight);

        try
        {
            gotFrame = true;

            if (videoControl != null)
            {
                hr = videoControl.SetMode(stillPin, VideoControlFlags.Trigger);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            }

            if (!pictureReady.WaitOne(9000, false))
            {
                throw new Exception("Timeout waiting to get picture");
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(imageBuffer);
            imageBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        return imageBuffer;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

DirectShow sets you up video streaming, hence you have a stream of frames, not  individual images such as obtained when pressing a button (in fact, response to button is untypical for DirectShow and is likely to require some camera-specific integration). `ISampleGrabberCB::SampleCB` is thus getting you every captured video frame sequentially. You don't poll it with timer, instead you have a callback called for every frame.

Since it sounds like you are not getting this, I suppose you are missing one of the two things, or both:

1. You can/need set capture resolution and pixel format of your interest - for image processing you might prefer uncompressed video formats rather than compressed
2. Callback calls are blocking, the slower is the frame processing the lower is effective frame rate since you are delaying video streaming with the video processing time.

Also note that some consumer grade cameras have higher resolution for snapshots and lower resolution for video streaming, so when it comes to video processing you are unable to reach highest declared resolution on the camera specification.

Comment: So would I use the IMediaSample given and convert it into a bitmap (as a bitmap is needed for the external library)?

Comment: Yes, and this is actually straightforward. Regular streaming does not use bitmaps exactly, so you have to obtains them from video frames in their streaming format.

Comment: I thought this would be the case, I currently have it working with the `ISampleGrabberCB::BufferCB` So that when a button is pressed the current frame is displayed in a smaller box and the barcode is then scanned giving me the string of numbers, So basically I am trying to achieve this automatically. Is there any general process  to convert the IMediaSample (which i assume is the current frame) into a bitmap?

Comment: You are putting the question incorrectly. You are getting the frames automatically already, so you don't need to use button, just connect callback call to whatever your button handler does. General process regarding `IMediaSample` does not exist. However, if the media samples are 24/32-bit RGB, you can use this interface methods to access data you have with BufferCB through pointer.

Comment: So basically I believe my BufferCB constantly saves the frames then when i click my button to executre the getFrameFromWebcam() function it calls the getFrame() function which then gets the current saved image and then the rest of the function converts to a bitmap and displays the numbers as a string. Is it ideal to move all of that into the BufferCB and will it stil work?

Comment: No need to put this into comments, you can edit the post instead. There is no single ideal solution, it depends on how the library works exactly. I suppose the best would be to copy frame into queue from `SampleCB` and then on a worker thread push this into analysis library.

Comment: Sorry new to stack overflow, how would I go about copying the frame using `SampleCB`? Would it just be the same as what I am currently doing in my `BufferCB`? My current google results have only found ways of using the `BufferCB` + I am new to directshow and know no C++ so its kind of difficult for me to interpret and convert code in this language

Comment: You can still edit the post and delete from the comments. If you are familiar with `BufferCB`, do via `BufferCB` - it can still work out.

Comment: I have tried to move everything into the `BufferCB` (and changed around the code slightly) however nothing happens, the application doesn't even load and I receive the error after about 10 seconds `Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\WindowsForm.exe" to "bin\Debug\WindowsForm.exe" the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`...Is the `BufferCB` called after every new frame is detected (I am presuming it is).

Comment: Can you offer anymore help?